# Looping through a list of dicts with Jinja for-loop

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, html-table, jinja2

My Jinja for loop prints the first values of my list the right amount of times, but it is just not getting the right values. Say

list contains

```
harry, male, 1994
samuel, male, 1998
```

it will print

```
harry, male, 1994
harry, male, 1994
```

What am i doing wrong here?

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Nationality </th>
            <th> Gender </th>
            <th> Study </th>
            <th> Email </th>
            <th> Password </th>
        </tr>
        {% for name, nationality, gender, study, email, password in students %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ name }} </td>
            <td> {{ nationality }} </td>
            <td> {{ gender }} </td>
            <td> {{ study }} </td>
            <td> {{ email }} </td>
            <td> {{ password }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>

</table>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Nationality </th>
            <th> Gender </th>
            <th> Study </th>
            <th> Email </th>
            <th> Password </th>
        </tr>
        {% for student in students %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ student['name'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ student['nationality'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ student['gender'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ student['study'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ student['email'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ student['password'] }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>

</table>

{% endblock %}
```

while making sure the first line of the csv file was:

```
1.name,nationality,gender,study,email,password
```